# RabbitMQ: a worker listen to many queue but get 1 message at a time

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a way that I can set up a worker that listen to a number of queue but will process only a single message from a single queue at a time?

Use case:
1. Task A
2. Task B
3. Task C

I want to have 10 workers. #1 - #3 can process Task A, #1 - #6 can process Task B and all of them can process Task C.

I used to let all of my workers listen to all of the queue, but they caused problems when some of tasks can't be processed by too many worker (eg. make too many concurrent request to another service.)

Letting a worker listen to a single queue waste its resource when it queue is empty while others are full.

Comment: Why don't you consolidate the queues? Have one Queue for Task A, one for B, one for C, and route the messages correctly?

Comment: `but will process only a single message from a single queue at a time`  Does this mean (a) or (b),     (a) #1 worker can process TaskA, TaskB & TaskC, but at a time only one Task should be running.    (b) #1 worker can process TaskA, TaskB & TaskC, if all 3 tasks are running simultaneously then it's accepted.

Comment: @ChetanGhodasara I mean that if Queue A, Queue B, Queue C have some messages in each queue. A worker will process only a message from one of these queue at a time. So it may processes Task A, Task B or Task C. But only one of them at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement, a worker can process any one task at a time, I would suggest making a single queue for all 3 types of messages and make all 10 workers as receiver of this common queue.
You can use custom header `AMQP.BasicProperties` --> `Map<String,Object> headers` to differentiate the messages.

For example,

**Sender and Queues:**

*(1) If you have control over Sender and Queues:*

Make single queue instead of 3 different queues, as shown below.
The sender will add custom header to each message before publishing it. `headers.put("type","Task#")`

[image]

*(2) If you don't have control over Sender and Queues:*

You can use `Processor` to add `headers.put("type","Task#")` into each message and send it to `common queue`. As shown below.

[image]

**Workers:**

Each worker can check type of the received message and behave accordingly.  Worker 4,5,6 can process TaskB & TaskC only. At a time anyone message will be processed. (As mentioned in below snippet - for reference only)

```
//Worker 4,5,6  (sample steps)
public void handler(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) {
    if(properties.getHeaders().get("type").equals("TaskA")) {
        // Negative acknowledgement - the message will be requeue.
    }
    else if(properties.getHeaders().get("type").equals("TaskB")) {
        // Convert body into TaskB (if required)
        // Process Task B
        // Positive acknowledgement
    }
    else if(properties.getHeaders().get("type").equals("TaskC")) {
        // Convert body into TaskC (if required)
        // Process Task C
        // Positive acknowledgement
    }
}
```

Comment: I have thought about this similar approach, but is it going to cause infinite loop if worker for job A haven't started?